# Qt SQL MYSQL Driver not loaded in shipping

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, driver

I know this question is asked 500 times a day but I can't help myself.

I have a QT Program which runs really fine in production, but when it comes to shipping it can't find the SQL driver.

I read that the libmysql.dll have to be in ./sqldrivers but its not working anyways.

Here are my Files for the project:

```
21.06.2016  15:00    <DIR>          .
21.06.2016  14:51    <DIR>          ..
21.06.2016  14:51           230.400 bass.dll
21.06.2016  14:51            36.864 basscd.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           203.776 Qt5Sql.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         5.664.256 Qt5Core.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         6.019.072 Qt5Gui.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         5.295.104 libmysql.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         5.472.768 Qt5Widgets.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           420.352 test.exe
21.06.2016  14:51           635.040 msvcp140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           332.968 concrt140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         5.624.984 mfc140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           105.120 mfcm140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           552.608 vcamp140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           390.320 vccorlib140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           205.984 vcomp140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51            88.752 vcruntime140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           213.680 VSCover140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51           274.600 VSPerf140.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         1.020.928 qwindows.dll
21.06.2016  14:52    <DIR>          platforms
21.06.2016  14:56    <DIR>          sqldrivers
              19 Datei(en),     32.787.576 Bytes
               4 Verzeichnis(se),     45.801.472 Bytes frei

/sqldrivers
21.06.2016  14:56    <DIR>          .
21.06.2016  15:00    <DIR>          ..
26.02.2015  00:27         5.191.680 libmysql.dll
               1 Datei(en),      5.191.680 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se),     45.801.472 Bytes frei

/platforms
21.06.2016  14:52    <DIR>          .
21.06.2016  15:00    <DIR>          ..
21.06.2016  14:52         1.249.280 qwindows.dll
21.06.2016  14:51            35.840 qminimal.dll
21.06.2016  14:51            99.840 qminimald.dll
21.06.2016  14:51         2.920.448 qminimald.pdb
21.06.2016  14:51           664.064 qoffscreen.dll
21.06.2016  14:52         1.304.576 qoffscreend.dll
21.06.2016  14:52         5.386.240 qoffscreend.pdb
21.06.2016  14:52         2.620.416 qwindowsd.dll
21.06.2016  14:52        12.578.816 qwindowsd.pdb
               9 Datei(en),     26.859.520 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se),     45.801.472 Bytes frei
```

Where is the problem here?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have the mysql plugin. You have the mysql library, used by the plugin, but not the plugin itself!

Comment: @Kuba Ober what ist the plugin exactly? is there a missing dll?

Comment: I think I found it, its the qsqlmysql.dll in the plugins folder isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

There it is, 
The qsqlmysql.dll (located in plugins/sqldrivers) was missing
I just copyed the dll into %Appdir%/sqldrivers and it works